# Copying excel data into a python list in IPython using clipboard?

Tags: python, ipython

Is there a way to perform the following workflow:

1. Select cells in an Excel spreadsheet
2. Copy them using Ctrl+C
3. Get the content the selected cells in a form of a python list or numpy array into the IPython shell?

Comment: Actually it's pretty clear what @Norfeldt is asking. I'll edit the question a little bit.

Comment: It is now fully clear what the is being asked. This question should be re-opened!!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Update:* It seems that the `readline` thing that @PauloAlmeida mentioned is turned on by default in the 1.0 verison of IPython. So all you have to do is:

1. `from numpy import array`
2. Copy the cells from the spreadsheet
3. Hit `Alt+V` instead of `Ctrl+V`

And you will get in IPython something like:

```
array([[1, 1], [2, 2]])
```

Or you can use the pandas library `read_clipboard` method.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.read_clipboard()            # If you have selected the headers
pd.read_clipboard(header=None) # If you haven't selected the headers
```

This will return you a pandas DataFrame object which acts similarly to a spreadsheet. You can find more about it in their official [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/).

Comment: This was exactly what I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I usually do:

### 1: get a csv file

Copy-paste the cells you want into a new Excel document.
Click 'File' then 'Save as'.
Select 'Save as type: CSV' .
Close Excel and open the file with notepad or other editor.

Now you have something like this:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

### 2: get a python list

You can either

- use [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to load your csv file; or
- use the search/replace functionality of your editor to replace start/end of lines with '[' and ']' then copy paste to ipython.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you can use [PyReadline](http://ipython.org/pyreadline.html), which has a smart paste feature:

> - Copy and paste using the clipboard
> - Smart paste for convenient use with ipython. Converting tab separated data to python list or numpy array.

See also the [documentation for clipboard functions](http://pythonhosted.org/pyreadline/usage.html#clipboard):

> ipython_paste
>
> Paste windows clipboard. If enable_ipython_paste_list_of_lists is True then try to convert tabseparated data to repr of list of lists or
>   repr of array. If enable_ipython_paste_for_paths==True then change \\
>   to / and spaces to \space.

Comment: How do you enable this feature cause I couldn't manage to do it :-/

Comment: I didn't include this in the original answer because it's a few years old, but maybe it's still helpful (information on binding the ipython_paste command to a key): http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/ipython-user/2010-January/006813.html