# Copying cells from Libreoffice Calc to IPython console in Spyder

Tags: python, numpy, spyder, libreoffice-calc

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311976/copying-excel-data-into-a-python-list-in-ipython-using-clipboard) asks almost exactly what I would like to know. However, the accepted answer does not work in the Spyder IDE, because when I press `Alt+V` the view tab in the menu bar opens.

Therefore, I rephrase the question: How can I copy the content of cells from Libreoffice Calc into a numpy array in the IPython console **in Spyder** using the clipboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder developer here*) After copying your data in Calc, you need to focus the Variable Explorer, do a right click on an empty space on it to get this menu:

[image: Variable Explorer context menu]

and then select *Paste*.

After that you will get this dialog

[image: Import data wizard]

and when pressing *Next*, you'll be able to import it in the current IPython console as a Numpy array:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem! And keep up the good work developing Spyder.