# "Space" get's lost when I copy-paste from Excel in to Python Shell

Tags: python, excel, python-3.7

I want to copy/paste following from Excel:

> [Word1  Word2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA8CA.png)

When I past it in the Python3.7 Shell it looks like that:

> [Word1Word2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wGOy.png)

Can I add something to the "input()" so that it recognize the space/tab that you have when copy cells from Excel?

Yes I know you can import Excel Files but that is not what I need in my script.
Thank you

Comment: This is probably because the Clipboard has to convert two cells to a string when you paste them. Maybe you can try to read the clipboard directly instead of using input()

Comment: how can you do that without importing the Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer in another thread:
[Copying excel data into a python list in IPython using clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311976/copying-excel-data-into-a-python-list-in-ipython-using-clipboard)

Basically you use pandas to get the data from the clipboard like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
...
# wait user to copy cells in excel
input() # wait for enter or whatever
cells = pd.read_clipboard() # read content from clipboard
...
```

This stores the data in a table format. From there you can do whatever with it.